# How can I get the builder name of the linux kernel

Tags: shell, linux-kernel

When the linux kernel booting up，it will print the kernel version and builder, and toolchain infomation. Just like below:

```
Booting Linux on physical CPU 0
Linux version 3.4.24 (whobuilderthis@cl-builder23)
```

So how to get the builder `whobuilderthis` string (using shell)? Where does it store? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could query `/proc/version` which should contain the builder string.

```
shell@android:/ $ cat /proc/version                                            
Linux version 3.0.31-g9f818de (android-build@vpbs1.mtv.corp.google.com) (gcc version 4.6.x-google 20120106 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Nov 28 11:20:29 PST 2012
```

Answer (score 1):

`dmesg` gives the kernel log, so you should be able to `grep`/`sed` it from there:

```
dmesg | grep 'Linux version ' | sed 's/[^(]*(\([^)]*\)).*/\1/'
```

(There are smarter ways of doing this.)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't illustrate the issue in detail: I want to get it during the Android booting up, when it run the init.hardware.rc. Currently, I use the exec to run a extra shell script, and I will try your given method later.

Answer (score 0):

According to Documentation/kbuild/kbuild.rst:

### KBUILD_BUILD_USER, KBUILD_BUILD_HOST

These two variables allow to override the user@host string displayed during
boot and in /proc/version. The default value is the output of the commands
whoami and host, respectively.

So "/proc/version" will output the result of current running kernel.
If you want to change the content, you need override the above 2 vars on your kernel build machine.